# Column constraint: allow growing only value

Tags: mysql, constraints

I would like to restrict values in mySql table column to satisfy the rule the new values inserted must be greater than any existing ones. As I cannot find any other than `UNIQUE` and `AUTOINCREMENT` constraints, I would like to ask, if there is any possibility to reach such functionality in mySql.

Comment: You can fire a trigger before insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement such functionality using a `before insert` trigger.

MySQL supports the *syntax* of check constraints, but it doesn't actually implement the logic.  That leaves trigger.

Also, there might be additional options if you edit your question and explain what the column is representing.  For an `id` type of column, for instance, you can use `autoincrement`.  If it is a cumulative sum of some sort, then perhaps storing the changes would make more sense than storing the total.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand the AI correctly, it is too restrictive due to its +1 increment (wouldn't like to hack it via playing the AI offset via `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 123`). There just must be possibility to allow +N increment. Take the column as a series of numbers where `next = last + N`, where `N > 0`.